# Is there a way to store mixins in a map in sass

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, mixins, scss-mixins

I want to include classes for different media queries based on a condition.

What im doing right now:

```
@mixin available($exclude-exp: each)
{
  @if($exclude-exp == each) {
    //include for each breakpoint
  }
  @else if($exclude-exp == global-only) {
    .available {
      flex:  1
    }
  }
  @else if($exclude-exp == medium-only) {
    @media screen and (min-width: $medium) {
      .onmedium-available {
        flex: 1
      }
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

It would be better for me if the `available` mixin is receiving the `$exclude-exps` as a map and loop through the map and then include all mixins within that map.

```
@mixin available($exclude-exps) {
  @each $exclude-exp in $exclude-exps {
    @include $exclude-exp();
  }
}

$exclude-exps:(
  each: @mixin() {
    //a mixin to include for each breakpoint
  },
  global-only: @mixin() {
    .available {
      flex: 1
    }
  },
  medium-only: @mixin() {
    @media screen and (min-width: $medium) {
      .onmedium-available {
        flex: 1
      }
    }
  },
  .
  .
  .
)
```

Then letter i can add as many `$exclude-exps` as i like.